# Handling asynchronous method exceptions in web3.js

Tags: web3js, javascript

I use web3.js 0.20.6.

The following code throws an exception:

```
        var abi = [/*...*/];
        var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
        var myContractInstance = MyContract.at("xxx");
        myContractInstance.owner.call(function(error, address) {
            alert(address);
        })
```

because `"xxx"` is not a valid contract address. (In practice instead of `"xxx"` is may be a wrong contract address entered by a user.)

How to catch such exceptions? I can't just put `.call` instead a `try`...`catch` block because it is a callback, not a synchronous call.

So how to catch such exceptions?

Comment: Hi there. I think this is likely to be closed as off-topic. It would probably be better to ask on Stack Overflow with the appropriate JS tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that this exception is thrown only on non-well-formed addresses.

The exception is not thrown on a correct `address` type argument even if the address does not exists.

So it seems viable to call `.call()` inside a `try`...`catch`.